# how do i put variables inside a mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have two variables like this

```
$date1 = $_POST['f_date1'];
$date2 = $_POST['f_date2'];
```

is this the correct way of putting it inside?

```
$sql = "SELECT location, COUNT(*) as Referrals,
        SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Hired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hired,
        SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
        FROM vtiger_leadscf
        LEFT JOIN vtiger_leaddetails ON vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vtiger_leaddetails.leadid
        WHERE location > '' AND (date_table BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')
        GROUP BY location 
        ORDER BY Referrals DESC";
```

Comment: Should be like this : `AND (date_table BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."')`

Comment: Only if you want to get hacked. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You need to use prepared statements.

Comment: @RubahMalam that's just wrong. The two versions do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, @EdCottrell was right. Your code is easy to inject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do this depends on what interface you are using to mysql.

If you are using the (old and deprecated) `mysql_*` interface (you shouldn't be), then at a *minimum*, before you use your variables you need to escape them using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

eg:

```
$date1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['f_date1']);
$date2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['f_date2']);
```

After which yes your query construction is fine (for this method, which you shouldn't use).

Ideally, you need to be using either [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), both of which support prepared statements. This example will be `PDO`, just because.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=whatever', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT location, COUNT(*) as Referrals,
        SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Hired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hired,
        SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
        FROM vtiger_leadscf
        LEFT JOIN vtiger_leaddetails ON vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vtiger_leaddetails.leadid
        WHERE location > '' AND (date_table BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)
        GROUP BY location 
        ORDER BY Referrals DESC");

$stmt->execute(array(
  'startDate' => $date1,
  'endDate' => $date2
));
```

Note inside the query the use of `:startDate` and `:endDate`. those are placeholders which get filled by the associative array passed to `$stmt->execute`.  Prepared statements are preferred as they prevent the nastiness that can occur when you simply concatenate unsanitised values into the query (look up: sql injection).

The `mysqli_` interface is more similar to the deprecated `mysql_` interface, but it also supports prepared statements.

mysqli method:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT location, COUNT(*) as Referrals,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Hired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hired,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
            FROM vtiger_leadscf
            LEFT JOIN vtiger_leaddetails ON vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vtiger_leaddetails.leadid
            WHERE location > '' AND (date_table BETWEEN ? AND ?)
            GROUP BY location 
            ORDER BY Referrals DESC");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $date1, $date2);

$stmt->execute();
```

Note the key difference there is the use of `?` as the placeholder (pdo also supports this, i simply prefer named placeholders), and the way the variables are bound. The `"ss"` specifies the 'type' of the value being bound.

My personal preference is for PDO, purely because I prefer its `execute` call with the array parameter.

Comment: syntax is the same when i am using mysqli?

Comment: it's a little different. is that what you are using?

Comment: @marse okay there you go, updated slightly with mysqli

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
$sql = "SELECT location, COUNT(*) as Referrals,
        SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Hired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hired,
        SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
        FROM vtiger_leadscf
        LEFT JOIN vtiger_leaddetails ON vtiger_leadscf.leadid = vtiger_leaddetails.leadid
        WHERE location > '' AND (date_table BETWEEN '" . $date1 . "' AND '" . $date2 . "')
        GROUP BY location 
        ORDER BY Referrals DESC";
```